# Android C code getaddrinfo takes a long time，but JAVA code InetAddress.getByName() is very fast

Tags: java, android, c, dns

C code

```
getaddrinfo(hostname, servname, hints, res);
```

JAVA code

```
java.net.InetAddress.getByName(host)
```

Parsing the same domain name, C takes seconds, but JAVA is very fast.

Comment: Do you compare the same queries ? (same hostname from same machine ?) eg : if the host is in the hosts file (/etc/hosts or C:\Windows\...\hosts), then the query is very fast. But if the query leads to a connection to a remote server, then it will take longer.

Comment: ipv6 cause getaddrinfo block

Comment: any workaround for this block ?